# How to insure MFMailComposeViewController doesnt send email when body is not empty?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have MFMailComposeViewController in my app in order to allow the user easily email me about suggestions and feedback on the app but I get about 3 emails a day which are just empty in the body or just the users email signature.

Is there any way of checking if the body of an email is not empty before it is sent with MFMailComposeViewController?

Answer (score 5):

This is not a programming answer, and might be a bit off topic, but I have released a few apps with similar functionality, and have seen the same thing.

I have also talked with a few of the users who have sent in empty emails, and have learned that sometimes they sere just trying out the various functions of the App, and sometimes they get to the feedback page, but don't want to take the time to type out an email on their phone.

I would think of this as more of a customer service problem, and less of a programming challenge.  I would use the opportunity to follow up with the users who send the empty emails.  (At least now you have their email - if you don't let them send the form without a body you will likely never get it.)  One option is to send a standard follow-up email that says you received an empty email from them and would love to hear their feedback on your product. (Perhaps even send them a quick survey) .

Comment: hmm good point, i have however got a very emails that are like random characters like: sjhfiuwehfjvzdnbliuh4w98rhwjls
I emailed a few of the people back and they said it was their baby messing with the device which I suspect most of my emails are due to

Answer (score 1):

Once you have displayed the MFMailComposeViewController's view you cannot get at the message or control the behaviour. You cannot stop people sending empty mails.

If you really want to do this you will have to write a replacement view and controller. It is probably easier to filter the blank mails at the receiving end though :-)

Comment: how can a replacement controller send mail?

Comment: SMTP is the normal way but you could also write your own gateway at a server.

Comment: but it's not the same because you will not be able to send it out from the user's email account

Comment: Entering mail address would be part of the implementation :-) if you control the SMTP server you can send from that account.